# Reading and splitting a CSV File with Talend

Tags: csv, talend

The csv file contains more than one table, it might look like this:

```
 "Table 1"
 ,
 "id","visits","downloads","emailsent"
  1, 4324, 23, 2
  2, 664, 42, 1
  3, 73, 44, 0
  4, 914, 8, 0
  ...

 "Table 2"
 ,
 "id_of_2nd_tab","visits_of_2nd_tab","downloads_of_2nd_tab"
  1, 524, 3
  2, 564, 52
  3, 63, 84
  4, 814, 8
  ...
```

What is the best way to import those tables into Talend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, that kind of multi-record format CSV format is more complex to parse.

Question : Are there are a finite number of tables?
Question: Does each table have a fixed number and order of columns?
Question: What is the separator between "tables" within the CSV?

I believe you need to take a multi-pass approach. You could do something like this.

Pass #1 - Use tFileInputDelimited
Use row separator such as "Table",  No field separator, Grab 1 big field
Alternatively, you could split the first file into separate files at this stage.

Pass #2 - Split Row (on results from pass #1) on the Row Separator "\r\n"  etc
Split it into multiple rows but of a single column.

Pass #3 - Extract Delimited Fields (on results from pass #2)
Extract based on a field separator
Recognize a "Table" row
Recognize a "Header row
Additional handling per Table / set of fields in header

Comment: yes, there are finite number of tables. But the number of rows is not fixed. The separator are two newlines

Comment: The first step, then, is read the file (define as 1 column in the Talend schema) and use two newlines  as the separator.  That will give you two "rows" of data.  Now, each row represents a separate table. 

What would you do next?

Answer (score 0):

Use the a tFileInputExcel component to read each worksheet.  Then you can use tMap to join the worksheets into a target column layout assuming you want do some processing on a joined set of columns.

Comment: I want to split CSV files, not Excel files

Comment: For csv use tFileInputDelimited component.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but how to splitt the csv file if it has more than one table ?